# trying to code of divisibility test using def function

Tags: python, for-loop

as you see the code below after I run it gives None at the end. How do I get rid of it

I am trying to get the numbers that are divisible by 5 in a given list of numbers

```
def num_divisibility(num_list):
     for num in num_list:
        if num % 5 == 0:
            print(num)
print(num_divisibility([10, 20, 33, 46, 55]))
```

**Output:-**

```
10
20
55
None
```

Comment: To get rid of the None at the end, remove the final line of code which prints the result of the function

Below is the fixed code  snippet 
```def num_divisibility(num_list):
 for num in num_list:
     if num % 5 == 0:
        print(num) 
num_divisibility([10, 20, 33, 46, 55]) ```

Answer (score 0):

You are already printing the numbers inside num_divisibility function. So, when you're calling the function inside of a print statement `print(num_divisibility([10, 20, 33, 46, 55]))`, it's gonna print the return value of the num_divisibility function. But `num_divisibility` got no return value, so it's gonna print `None`. Just call your num_divisibility function without print statement as mentioned in comments.